# ARCore Android SDK – How to make a scaling animation on Transformable node?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I am trying to add scaling animation to Transformable Node (3D model) when I tap on it.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can add a scaling animation to Transformable Node using the following code:

```
Anchor yourAnchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
AnchorNode anchoringNode = new AnchorNode(yourAnchor);

modelNode.getScaleController().setMinScale(1.50f);
modelNode.getScaleController().setMaxScale(2.00f);
modelNode.setLocalScale(new Vector3(1.75f, 1.75f, 1.75f));
modelNode.setParent(anchoringNode);
```